# C# Windows form. CheckBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать, чтобы если один чекбокс активен, при нажатии на другой выбирался этот чекбокс, а с прежнего галочка удалялась?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть вам нужны RadioButton?

Если их поместить в какой-нибудь контейнер, то они будут работать, как вы описали "из коробки".

Если вам нужны именно CheckBox, то подписывайтесь на события и обрабатывайте снятие галочек вручную.

Comment: Могли бы привести пример включения галки при нажатии на чекбокс и выключения со старого? Если не сложно

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-respond-to-windows-forms-checkbox-clicks

Answer (score 1):

Помещате их в Panel примеру

и вот так

код вставтиь в обработчик нажатия галочки

```
panel.Controls.TypeOf<CheckBox>().ForeEach(c => 
{
   c.Checked = false;
});

(CheckBox(sender)).Checked= true;
```

Comment: Ошибка CS1061 "IEnumerable<CheckBox>" не содержит определения для "ForeEach", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "ForeEach", принимающий тип "IEnumerable<CheckBox>" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку). twrc3 C:\Users\...\source\repos\twrc3\twrc3\Form1.cs 105 Активный

Comment: опечатка писал на пямять надо ForEach или просто в цикле переберите